# How to remove swap from RAID1 Array?

Tags: raid, swap, format

Can anyone point in the right direction on how to remove SWAP out of a RAID1 configuration? According to the Ubuntu Advanced installation guide, [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/advanced-installation.html), it said to add swap to the raid but I am having some serious performance issues. I would like to remove it from the array and recreate it, with the same size, on the two separate drives. Zero data loss on the data array is a must.

Its a remote computer so I would prefer to do it via command-line if possible.

> Here is the output from cat /proc/mdstat
>
> md0 : active raid1 sdb1[1] sda1[0]
>         19530688 blocks [2/2] [UU]
>
> md1 : active raid1 sdb2[1] sda2[0]
>         957230016 blocks [2/2] [UU]

The swap device is md0.

Comment: You may want to ask a new question about your performance problems--swap on RAID 1 should perform fine, unless your drives' interface is slow and they are on the same controller. (Related: [Should swap and RAID-1 mix?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/245976/should-swap-and-raid-1-mix))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is no different than managing any other swap partition:

Use `swapoff mdX` to remove it from consideration for swap usage.

Then use `mdadm` to take that array out of service and then delete it.
`man mdadm`,

and the [Software RAID HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Software-RAID-HOWTO.html#toc5) is very clear on these administrative tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to your question, but anyone looking at this might want to [look at this anser](https://askubuntu.com/a/246002/295317) before deciding to move their swap off RAID1. That answer gives a nice overview of the considerations involved and might convince you to keep your swap in the RAID1 :-)